# ¿Como filtrar con bindingSource. Filter, cadena de texto con literales? En C#

Tags: c#, filtro, like

**Hola:**

He intentado filtrar por un campo de texto (string) que contiene latitud, por ejemplo:

41°1'.4"N

Bs.Filter lo codifica como:

"41°1'.4\"N"

El primer intento es este:
(campo, es una variable string con el nombre del campo, y texto una string, con el contenido)

```
Bs.Filter = campo + "LIKE'*" + texto +  "*'";
```

(No funciona, entiende texto con literal y secuencia de escape "41°1'.4\"N")

Otro intento dando formato al texto:

```
Bs.Filter = campo +(string.Format("Convert(" + texto + ", 'System.String') LIKE '*{0}*'")) ;
```

(da un error: "índice basado en 0 debe ser >= 0 y menor que lista argumentos...")

He probado un montón de cosas, ya no se me ocurre, ¿el problema está en el 0?

Alguien puede ayudar. Gracias anticipadas.
Rafael

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está en la comilla simple que está después del segundo `1`. Las comillas simples funcionan como un contenedor de un string y tu problema se debe a ese string contiene otra comilla simple. Para estos casos debes usar 2 veces la comilla simple dentro del string.

Ejemplo

```
//                           v---Aquí 2 comillas simples
Bs.Filter = "Latitud = '41°1''.4\"N'";
```

Tu estas utilizando un texto a modo de variable, entonces deberás reemplazar la comilla simple por 2 comillas simples

```
string texto = "41°1'.4\"N";
Bs.Filter = $"Latitud = '{texto.Replace("'","''")}'";
```

Comment: @Rafael No entiendo el comentario, la sintaxis es 100% compatible con C#. La barra invertida se usa para agregar comilla dobles

Comment: @Rafael aquí puedes ver como funciona https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOy1M.png